# Are there any letter icons for flutter(Icons showing a,b,c,d....)?

Tags: flutter, icons

I just need to provide icons for few toggle buttons showing letters(specifically M T W R F S S representing week days) and I can't find any in standard icons in flutter and font awesome package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/mdi

Search for alphabet on https://materialdesignicons.com/ to see which ones are in there.