# Imported mdi icon is not rendering in flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use an mdi imported icon instead of the regular icons that flutter provides.

I tried following the link:
[Are there any letter icons for flutter(Icons showing a,b,c,d....)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62830648/are-there-any-letter-icons-for-fluttericons-showing-a-b-c-d)

I edited my dependencies in `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  mdi: ^3.0.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

And imported mdi

```
import 'package:mdi/mdi.dart';
```

This is an attempt to use the icon

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Mdi.alphaCCircleOutline),
              label: '',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Mdi.alphaHCircleOutline),
              label: '',
            )
          ],
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          selectedItemColor:
              _currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.indigo[400],
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _currentIndex = index;
            });
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

However, the result is as follow,

[image]

Is my import correct?

Comment: set `uses-material-design: true` in pubspec file . If that doesn't help. Uninstall the app and start run again

Comment: thank you. A restart of the app (R) solved this for me. thanks @ProblematicDude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `uses-material-design: true` in pubspec file .
If that doesn't help. Uninstall the app and start run again